# LDAP SearchResponse to Json C#

Tags: c#, json, ldap

I am using a C# LdapConnection to get a SearchResponse at work.  I can get the SearchResponse into a Json string, but am unable to put that Json string into an object class with properties which mimic the SearchResponse.  The Json string is properly formatted.  Am I using the Newtonsoft.Json library in the wrong way?  Is there a better way to do this?  My only requirements are that I get a SearchResponse into my object class (DirectoryEntity) so I can use it from there.

My Console Application:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LdapClient client = new LdapClient();
            List<LdapSearchResponseModel> list = new List<LdapSearchResponseModel>();
            string query = "(|(uupid=name1)(uupid=name2))";
            string[] attributes = new string[] { };
            string host = "id.directory.univ";
            int port = 1234;
            SearchResponse response = client.RawQuery(query, attributes, host, port);

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);

            var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DirectoryEntities>(json);
        }
    }
```

My DirectoryEntity Class:

```
public class DirectoryEntity
    {
        public string EntityDN { get; set; }
        public int MailStop { get; set; }
        public List<string> UniversityAffiliation { get; set; }
        public int UniversityId { get; set; }
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string PasswordState { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string AccountState { get; set; }
        public int Uid { get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; }
        public string MailPreferredAddress { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public List<string> GroupMembership { get; set; }
        public string DegreeType { get; set; }
        public int ClassLevelCode { get; set; }
        public string AuthId { get; set; }
        public string Major { get; set; }
        public string ClassLevel { get; set; }
        public bool SupressDisplay { get; set; }
        public string UnderGraduateLevel { get; set; }
        public string ObjectClass { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentNumber { get; set; }
        public List<string> EduPersonAffiliation { get; set; }
        public string LocalPostalAddress { get; set; }
        public string Uupid { get; set; }
        public string LocalPhone { get; set; }
        public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Sn { get; set; }
    }
```

My DirectoryEntities Class:

```
public class DirectoryEntities
{
    public List<DirectoryEntity> Entities { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [DirectorySearcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult(v=vs.110).aspx)?  It returns a DirectoryEntry class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly defining a default constructor for the DirectoryEntity class? I believe that Newtonsoft requires objects to have a default constructor before they can be deserialized. Try adding this to the DirectoryEntity class:

```
public DirectoryEntity() { }
```